# After adding Watch Kit Target: com.apple.actool.errors "No such file or directory" with Image Assets

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, watchkit, xcode6.3

I just made a branch in my iOS project and added a target for an WatchKit App in there. When I hit build and run now I get this strange error:

```
: error: Failed to read file attributes for "/Users/philip.brechler/Documents/motortalk/ForumApp/ForumApp/Images.xcassets /Users/philip.brechler/Documents/motortalk/ForumApp/MOTOR-TALK WatchKit App/Images.xcassets /Users/philip.brechler/Documents/motortalk/ForumApp/MOTOR-TALK WatchKit Extension/Images.xcassets"
Failure Reason: No such file or directory
```

The directories exist of course and I didn't change anything else then adding the target. I also tried this twice with the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the new version of Cocoapods fixed this for me.